# Principal Component Regression? What is the dependent variable?

Tags: r, regression, pca

I am performing a `PCA` to try to flush out the highly correlated variables real coefficients.  I have a very large dataset but will try to simplify here. I have the formula:

```
lm(y~x1+x2+x3...x55) -> reg_linear_model
```

The issue I am having is that `x1:x4` are all **very highly correlated** and some of them are coming in negative because of this.  When I try I perform [pca](/questions/tagged/pca) I get the list of components and their values.  I would like to to test which components to use but the dependent Y is three years of data broken up by week so it is `y1, y2, y3, y4, ....y156. 156 weeks`.  The issue I am having is that I cannot regress the components towards y because the lengths are different.  Do I need to transform Y in some way to get it to fit into the number of rows as components?  It is very hard to find an answer for this.  A lot of PCR explanations just say to regress components onto y but Y is not in the [pca](/questions/tagged/pca).

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: You need to have the same number of rows for both inputs and outputs. So if the y values are weekly them aggregate your input values by week then compute the PCA and use the top few components in the regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do it like this, we can use the iris dataset, and let's make Sepal.Length the dependent, and others independent variable.

First of all, there's correlation between the dependent Petal.Width and Petal.Length:

```
cor(iris[,2:4])
             Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Width    1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
Petal.Length  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
Petal.Width   -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

Like you said, if we do regression, we see one of them go negative:

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ .,data=iris[,1:4]))

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris[, 1:4])

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.82816 -0.21989  0.01875  0.19709  0.84570 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.85600    0.25078   7.401 9.85e-12 ***
Sepal.Width   0.65084    0.06665   9.765  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Length  0.70913    0.05672  12.502  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width  -0.55648    0.12755  -4.363 2.41e-05 ***
```

We do a PCA, and get the principal components, which is under the `$x`:

```
pca=prcomp(iris[,2:4])
cor(iris[,"Sepal.Length"],pca$x)
           PC1       PC2       PC3
[1,] 0.8619141 -0.279587 0.1937703

data = data.frame(
Sepal.Length=iris[,"Sepal.Length"],
pca$x)

summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ .,data=data))

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.82816 -0.21989  0.01875  0.19709  0.84570 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.84333    0.02568 227.519  < 2e-16 ***
PC1          0.37123    0.01340  27.697  < 2e-16 ***
PC2         -0.58457    0.06506  -8.984 1.22e-15 ***
PC3          0.86983    0.13969   6.227 4.80e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The PC components are not correlated and you can use them for regression. If you have a lot of variables, you can also choose by correlation with the target variable as above.

Comment: This is great thank you.  I have a few more questions.  I want to find a replacement coefficient for the regular linear regression that came in positive,  How would I take the PCR and apply it the negative Peta.Width coefficient in the first regression?

Comment: You got to take all the correlated chunk out, so in my example, something like data = data.frame(Sepal.Length[,1:2],pca$x[,1:2]), this will exclude the last two correlated variables

Comment: In your case, please put all the variables together in a data.frame called data. Then do, pca = prcomp(data[,1:4]) ; newdata = data.frame(pca$x[,1:2],data[,-c(1:4)]) and do the regression again

Comment: prcomp(data[,1:4]) ; newdata = data.frame(pca$x[,1:2],data[,-c(1:4)]) 
cbind("Actual" = dependent$Actual, newdata)-> newmodel

summary(lm(Actual ~ PC1 + PC2, data = newmodel)) Call:
lm(formula = Actual ~ PC1 + PC2, data = newmodel)

I am still a little uncertain as to how this takes over the new coefficient, would the first two PCAs x values be the new coefficients in a linear combo?  The coefficients of PC 1 and PC2 are very high

Comment: Got it, I am like one step away from completely understanding this, is there a another platform I could quickly chat with you on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210232/discussion-between-d3hero23-and-stupidwolf).

Comment: When you say take the correlated chunk out, I have 4 highly correlated variables with each other not the dependent, so x14, x15, x16, x17 are all highly correlated...... so prcomp(data[,14:17]) ; newdata = data.frame(pca$x[,1:2],data[,-c(1:4)]) would be.....prcomp(data[,1:4]) ; newdata = data.frame(pca$x[,1:2],data[,-c(14:17)])..... and then the principal component coeff would be the new coeff in the original model?

Comment: yes that would be correct. The chat gallery is still blocked for u?